# How to hide the Floating Action Button from Bottom App Bar Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm creating a [Bottom App Bar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/) with an Floating Action Button. The App Bar is part of my Main Activity and I want to hide the FAB for some Fragments within the Activity.

I already tried 'View.GONE' and 'fab.hide()'. Then I tried to hide the Fab with following function:

```
    private fun hideFloatingActionButton() {
        val params = fab.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = params.behavior as FloatingActionButton.Behavior?

        if (behavior != null) {
            behavior.isAutoHideEnabled = false
        }

        params.anchorId = View.NO_ID;
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;
        fab.layoutParams = params
        fab.hide()
    }
```

My layout.xml:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/backPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

         content
    ...

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_burger_menu"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
    />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_project_day"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
    />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: When are you call the `hideFloatingActionButton ` method

Comment: I'm using the Navigation Component. When a fragment start, I send an event to the activity and call the ´hideFloatingActionButton()´ from the activity, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested out with fab.hide() method and it works. The "logic" to hide the fab should occur in the activity and not in the fragment. The next logic is set in the activity and the hide part is inside the else branch at the end.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, _ ->

        bar.animate().translationY(0f)


        // First page is main menu
        if(controller.graph.startDestination == destination.id){


            bar.navigationIcon = icon
            bar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER
            fab?.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_local_wtf))

        }else{

            // Hide navigation drawer icon
            bar.navigationIcon = null

            // Move FAB from the center of BottomAppBar to the end of it
            bar.fabAlignmentMode = BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END



            // Replace the action menu
            //bar.replaceMenu(bottomappbar_menu_secondary)
            invalidateOptionsMenu()

            // Change FAB icon
            fab?.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_reply_white_24dp))
            fab.hide()
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm also using the Navigation Component. When a fragment start, I send an event to the activity and call the ´hideFloatingActionButton()´ from the activity, if necessary. The problem is, that I have a nested navicgation graph and because of that I am not able to use the `OnDestinationChangedListener`.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your event. I just made a stupid test doing (requireActivity() as HomeActivity/*cast to your activity*/).hideTheFAB() in my Fragment inside onActivityCreated method and inside my Activity hideTheFab method i add fab.hide() only and it still works out this way

Comment: I found a problem in my event system. Thank you for your help.